# How can I use a value which includes "" within an echo?

Tags: bash, networking

I wrote a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script which automatically configures a setting file for some application.

The application uses a similar syntax to `/etc/sysconfig/network` file, the only exception is that it requires the values to be in double quotes `" "`.

So the line in the script looks something like this, but I don't know how to allow the double quotes of the ip address within the `echo`:

```
echo " ipaddr="1.1.1.1" " > file
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the quotes with a backslash character or use single quotes:

```
echo "ipaddr=\"1.1.1.1\""
echo 'ipaddr="1.1.1.1"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options:

1. Escape the double-quotes with single-quotes:

   ```
   echo ' ipaddr="1.1.1.1" ' > file
   ```
2. Escape the double-quotes with backslashes:

   ```
   echo "ipaddr=\"1.1.1.1\"" > file
   ```

In general, you can use a backslash to escape any single character; and you can use one type of quote to escape the other.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers all provide excellent ways of solving your problem. I'd just like to add one using `printf`, that can make things comfortable if, e.g., the ip address is stored in a variable:

```
ip=1.1.1.1

printf 'ipaddr="%s"\n' "$ip" > file
```

But here again, as in the other answers, you'll need to play with both, single and double quotes.

Things will be comfortable in this case (still assuming the ip is in the variable `ip`), because with `echo` instead of `printf`, you'd have to use either:

```
echo "ipaddr=\"$ip\"" > file
# or
echo 'ip addr="'"$ip"'"' > file
```

(ok, it's not a big deal, but I usually like `printf` better than `echo` in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)).

Answer (score 1):

you got the choice:

you can use different quotes inner and outer of the echo

```
echo "ipaddr='1.1.1.1'" > file
echo 'ipaddr="1.1.1.1"' > file
```

you can escape the quotes:

```
echo "ipaddr=\"1.1.1.1\"" > file
```

or you can make it simpler (but with escapes on the quotes):

```
echo ipaddr=\"1.1.1.1\" > file
```